# Android ListView as DirectoryListener and EditText (multiline) as TextEditor

Tags: android, file, android-listview, android-edittext, android-file

I'm developing an android application with NDK interface/library.
At the moment I designed all the Java classes/activities and methods that further will call the native c++ functions.

Before going on, I'd like to ask you a question:

I designed a TextEditor activity for creating a new TXT file.
First: I want to store the file on storage and app folder, is it feasible?
Second: Which would be the directory where I can find the files?

I designed a DirectoryList activity, which includes a ListView.
First: I want to show the previously saved TXT files in the list, by searching in the right folder and carrying out only the files I need (with a prefix "a_"), how can it be done?
Second: Can I add a "double click" feature to the list items, so that I can re-open the TextEditor for modifying the files?

Thank you in advance.
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Solved as following:

```
ListOfFile.setClickable(true);
        ListOfFile.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

              String name_of_file = ListOfFile.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

              Intent myIntent = new Intent();
              myIntent.setClass(DirectoryListener.this, TextViewer.class);
              Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
              bundle.putString ("filename", name_of_file);
              myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
              startActivity(myIntent);
              finish();

          }
        });
```